# Can't open activity onPushOpen(parse.com)

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

Sorry for my English. I create custom notifications(use parse.com and lib). I want it like this: I get notifications -> click this -> open new activity. I spend many times to fix this, but didn't have success. My code:

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    int mNotificationId = 001;


    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000});
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon); //You can change your icon
        mBuilder.setContentText("Content");
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
        mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.beep1));
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch a new activity which can display the new notification on a sperate screen/layout.

For that go to your ParseApplication.java

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, keys.applicationId, keys.clientKey);
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, NewActivity.java);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveEventually();
    }
```

Basically when ever you get a notification and the user clicks, it loads the NewActivity.java which in turn opens the xml file.

Now in `NewActivity.java` go to its `onCreate` in that in `setContentView`

```
setContentView(R.layout.**layout name**);
```

put your xml file.

Don't forget to add the activity in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to open the intended activity by using following code snippet!

```
@Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
            ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(context, NewFragment.class);
            ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, NewFragment.class);
            i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPushOpen Error : " + e);
        }
    }
```